# How to save value of inner json array data in model class and show in list

Tags: java, android

```
{
  "Response": {
    "ResponseCode": 1,
    "ResponseText": "Success"
  },
  "Detail": [
    {
      "DateOfSlot": "08/22/2018",
      "AvailableTimeSlots": [
        {
          "TimeSlotId": 46,
          "TimeOfSlot": "01:00PM",
          "TimeofSlotDateTime": "2018-08-22T13:00:00"
        },
        {
          "TimeSlotId": 48,
          "TimeOfSlot": "01:15PM",
          "TimeofSlotDateTime": "2018-08-22T13:15:00"
        }
      ],
      "ScheduleId": 4194,
      "GetBlockedTimings": [
        {
          "DateOfSlot": "8/22/201812:00:00AM",
          "AvailableTimeSlots": null,
          "ScheduleId": 0,
          "GetBlockedTimings": null,
          "BlockId": 1822,
          "fkTimeId": 43,
          "IsDeleted": false,
          "fkScheduledId": 4194,
          "utcDateOfSlot": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        }
      ],
      "BlockId": 0,
      "fkTimeId": 0,
      "IsDeleted": false,
      "fkScheduledId": 0,
      "utcDateOfSlot": "2018-08-22T00:00:00Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have above json array . From this array I want to show 'timeofslot'parameter value in list. if someone can guide me how I can do this with json parsing without help of GSON that will be helpful for me.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Redman ,I want to get values from server and then want to display in listview.I just searched on google but not got anything so i posted .

Comment: post , what have you tried so far . You should not expect us to write code for you . Write code your self, if some thing is wrong with code and you are not able to figue it out ,then post a question here and you will get better help

Answer (score 0):

You can simply parse this as follow

Create a Model class as

```
public class TimeSlot {

    public String TimeSlotId;
    public String TimeOfSlot;

    public String TimeofSlotDateTime;

    public TimeSlot(String timeSlotId, String timeOfSlot, String timeofSlotDateTime) {
        TimeSlotId = timeSlotId;
        TimeOfSlot = timeOfSlot;
        TimeofSlotDateTime = timeofSlotDateTime;
    }
}
```

Then use this class with `ArrayList`.

```
 ArrayList<TimeSlot> ovbjTimeSlots = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray jaDetail = jo.getJSONArray("Detail");
        for (int i = 0; i < jaDetail.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = jaDetail.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("AvailableTimeSlots");
            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
                String TimeSlotId = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("TimeSlotId");
                String TimeOfSlot = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("TimeOfSlot");
                String TimeofSlotDateTime = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("TimeofSlotDateTime");
                ovbjTimeSlots.add(new TimeSlot(TimeSlotId, TimeOfSlot, TimeofSlotDateTime));
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: how I'll save it in model class?

Comment: I want to save all values including both array .now tell me how I'll save all values in model class then how I'll display both array values in list.

Comment: @lavika please follow simple tutorial and learn how to show values to list https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: I couldn't so that's why I posted.I read many but not a single eg . I got where user is saving all the values of json array including inner array in json

Comment: You have to understand it step by step i can send you more simple exmples. if you want

Comment: Please see this example http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/

Comment: @lavika you can see by using ovbjTimeSlots.add. we are adding values to the list from JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseString);
List<String> timeOfSlot = new ArrayList<String>
for(int i = 0;i<json.getJSONArray("Detail).length(); i++){
for(int j=0;j<json.getJSONArray("Detail).get(i).getJSONArray("AvailableTimeSlots").length();j++)
timeOfSlot.add(json.getJSONArray("Detail).get(i).getJSONArray("AvailableTimeSlots").get(j).getString("timeofslot'parameter"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows,

```
JSONObject   jsonObject     = new JSONObject(response);
List<String> timeOfSlotList = new ArrayList<String>();

JSONArray jsonDetail = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Detail");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonDetail.length(); i++) {
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonDetail.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("AvailableTimeSlots");
    for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
         String timeSlotId = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("TimeSlotId");
         timeOfSlotList.add(timeSlotId);
    }
}
```

Comment: @lavika please edit the question accordingly. U asked as I want to show 'timeofslot'parameter value in list.

Answer (score 0):

I use jackjson to parse;

```
private List<String> parseString(String str) throws IOException {
    if(str == null){
        return null;
    }
    List<String> list =new ArrayList<>();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(str).get("Detail");
    for(int i=0 ; i< rootNode.size() ;i++){
        JsonNode rootnode1 =rootNode.get(i).get("AvailableTimeSlots");
        for(int j =0 ; j<rootnode1.size() ;j++){
            JsonNode rootnode2 =rootnode1.get(j);
            list.add((rootnode2.get("TimeOfSlot")).toString());
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.Model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class Model_Json {

    @SerializedName("Response")
    @Expose
    private Response response;
    @SerializedName("Detail")
    @Expose
    private List<Detail> detail = null;

    public Response getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(Response response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    public List<Detail> getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }

    public void setDetail(List<Detail> detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
    }


    public class Response {

        @SerializedName("ResponseCode")
        @Expose
        private Integer responseCode;
        @SerializedName("ResponseText")
        @Expose
        private String responseText;

        public Integer getResponseCode() {
            return responseCode;
        }

        public void setResponseCode(Integer responseCode) {
            this.responseCode = responseCode;
        }

        public String getResponseText() {
            return responseText;
        }

        public void setResponseText(String responseText) {
            this.responseText = responseText;
        }

    }


    public class GetBlockedTiming {

        @SerializedName("DateOfSlot")
        @Expose
        private String dateOfSlot;
        @SerializedName("AvailableTimeSlots")
        @Expose
        private Object availableTimeSlots;
        @SerializedName("ScheduleId")
        @Expose
        private Integer scheduleId;
        @SerializedName("GetBlockedTimings")
        @Expose
        private Object getBlockedTimings;
        @SerializedName("BlockId")
        @Expose
        private Integer blockId;
        @SerializedName("fkTimeId")
        @Expose
        private Integer fkTimeId;
        @SerializedName("IsDeleted")
        @Expose
        private Boolean isDeleted;
        @SerializedName("fkScheduledId")
        @Expose
        private Integer fkScheduledId;
        @SerializedName("utcDateOfSlot")
        @Expose
        private String utcDateOfSlot;

        public String getDateOfSlot() {
            return dateOfSlot;
        }

        public void setDateOfSlot(String dateOfSlot) {
            this.dateOfSlot = dateOfSlot;
        }

        public Object getAvailableTimeSlots() {
            return availableTimeSlots;
        }

        public void setAvailableTimeSlots(Object availableTimeSlots) {
            this.availableTimeSlots = availableTimeSlots;
        }

        public Integer getScheduleId() {
            return scheduleId;
        }

        public void setScheduleId(Integer scheduleId) {
            this.scheduleId = scheduleId;
        }

        public Object getGetBlockedTimings() {
            return getBlockedTimings;
        }

        public void setGetBlockedTimings(Object getBlockedTimings) {
            this.getBlockedTimings = getBlockedTimings;
        }

        public Integer getBlockId() {
            return blockId;
        }

        public void setBlockId(Integer blockId) {
            this.blockId = blockId;
        }

        public Integer getFkTimeId() {
            return fkTimeId;
        }

        public void setFkTimeId(Integer fkTimeId) {
            this.fkTimeId = fkTimeId;
        }

        public Boolean getIsDeleted() {
            return isDeleted;
        }

        public void setIsDeleted(Boolean isDeleted) {
            this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
        }

        public Integer getFkScheduledId() {
            return fkScheduledId;
        }

        public void setFkScheduledId(Integer fkScheduledId) {
            this.fkScheduledId = fkScheduledId;
        }

        public String getUtcDateOfSlot() {
            return utcDateOfSlot;
        }

        public void setUtcDateOfSlot(String utcDateOfSlot) {
            this.utcDateOfSlot = utcDateOfSlot;
        }

    }




    public class Detail {

        @SerializedName("DateOfSlot")
        @Expose
        private String dateOfSlot;
        @SerializedName("AvailableTimeSlots")
        @Expose
        private List<AvailableTimeSlot> availableTimeSlots = null;
        @SerializedName("ScheduleId")
        @Expose
        private Integer scheduleId;
        @SerializedName("GetBlockedTimings")
        @Expose
        private List<GetBlockedTiming> getBlockedTimings = null;
        @SerializedName("BlockId")
        @Expose
        private Integer blockId;
        @SerializedName("fkTimeId")
        @Expose
        private Integer fkTimeId;
        @SerializedName("IsDeleted")
        @Expose
        private Boolean isDeleted;
        @SerializedName("fkScheduledId")
        @Expose
        private Integer fkScheduledId;
        @SerializedName("utcDateOfSlot")
        @Expose
        private String utcDateOfSlot;

        public String getDateOfSlot() {
            return dateOfSlot;
        }

        public void setDateOfSlot(String dateOfSlot) {
            this.dateOfSlot = dateOfSlot;
        }

        public List<AvailableTimeSlot> getAvailableTimeSlots() {
            return availableTimeSlots;
        }

        public void setAvailableTimeSlots(List<AvailableTimeSlot> availableTimeSlots) {
            this.availableTimeSlots = availableTimeSlots;
        }

        public Integer getScheduleId() {
            return scheduleId;
        }

        public void setScheduleId(Integer scheduleId) {
            this.scheduleId = scheduleId;
        }

        public List<GetBlockedTiming> getGetBlockedTimings() {
            return getBlockedTimings;
        }

        public void setGetBlockedTimings(List<GetBlockedTiming> getBlockedTimings) {
            this.getBlockedTimings = getBlockedTimings;
        }

        public Integer getBlockId() {
            return blockId;
        }

        public void setBlockId(Integer blockId) {
            this.blockId = blockId;
        }

        public Integer getFkTimeId() {
            return fkTimeId;
        }

        public void setFkTimeId(Integer fkTimeId) {
            this.fkTimeId = fkTimeId;
        }

        public Boolean getIsDeleted() {
            return isDeleted;
        }

        public void setIsDeleted(Boolean isDeleted) {
            this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
        }

        public Integer getFkScheduledId() {
            return fkScheduledId;
        }

        public void setFkScheduledId(Integer fkScheduledId) {
            this.fkScheduledId = fkScheduledId;
        }

        public String getUtcDateOfSlot() {
            return utcDateOfSlot;
        }

        public void setUtcDateOfSlot(String utcDateOfSlot) {
            this.utcDateOfSlot = utcDateOfSlot;
        }

    }


    public class AvailableTimeSlot {

        @SerializedName("TimeSlotId")
        @Expose
        private Integer timeSlotId;
        @SerializedName("TimeOfSlot")
        @Expose
        private String timeOfSlot;
        @SerializedName("TimeofSlotDateTime")
        @Expose
        private String timeofSlotDateTime;

        public Integer getTimeSlotId() {
            return timeSlotId;
        }

        public void setTimeSlotId(Integer timeSlotId) {
            this.timeSlotId = timeSlotId;
        }

        public String getTimeOfSlot() {
            return timeOfSlot;
        }

        public void setTimeOfSlot(String timeOfSlot) {
            this.timeOfSlot = timeOfSlot;
        }

        public String getTimeofSlotDateTime() {
            return timeofSlotDateTime;
        }

        public void setTimeofSlotDateTime(String timeofSlotDateTime) {
            this.timeofSlotDateTime = timeofSlotDateTime;
        }

    }



}
```

> implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'

```
     List<Model_Json> jsonList= new Gson().fromJson("your_json",new TypeToken<List<Model_Json>>(){}.getType());
     List<Model_Json.AvailableTimeSlot> timeSlots =jsonList.get(0).getDetail().get(0).getAvailableTimeSlots();
```

Here timeSlots is a list which you can use to set adapter.

> ```
>  ArrayAdapterItem adapter = new ArrayAdapterItem(this, R.layout.list_view_row_item, timeSlots);
>
>   ListView listViewItems = findViewById(R.id.yourId);
>
>   listViewItems.setAdapter(adapter);
> ```

```
// here's our beautiful adapter
public class ArrayAdapterItem extends ArrayAdapter<Model_Json.AvailableTimeSlot> {

    Context mContext;
    int layoutResourceId;
    List<Model_Json.AvailableTimeSlot> data;


    public ArrayAdapterItem(Context mContext, int layoutResourceId, List<Model_Json.AvailableTimeSlot> data) {

        super(mContext, layoutResourceId, data);

        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        if(convertView==null){
            // inflate the layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        }

        // object item based on the position
        Model_Json.AvailableTimeSlot objectItem = data.get(position);

        // get the TextView and then set the text (item name) and tag (item ID) values
        TextView textViewItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);
        textViewItem.setText(objectItem.getTimeOfSlot());


        return convertView;

    }

}
```

> list_view_row_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Item name here..."
        android:textSize="15dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: how i can set it inside adapter . please tell me this.I have developed this class. I don't know how i can access timeslots values in set in adapter.